# trying to install pip for python3.6 - setuptools not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip, centos7

Why does python think I'm missing setuptools? It's right here:

```
[me@my_server site-packages]$ pwd
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[me@my_server site-packages]$ ll
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root   83 May  9 21:11 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   26 May  9 21:01 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  126 May  9 21:06 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root   56 May  9 21:11 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    6 Jan  4 16:42 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root 4.0K May  9 21:10 setuptools
[me@my_server site-packages]$ pwd
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[me@my_server site-packages]$ python3 easy_install.py pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "easy_install.py", line 4, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 47, in <module>
    from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 203, in <module>
    sys.version[:3], require('setuptools')[0].version
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 962, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools' distribution was not found and is required by the application



$ ll setuptools/
total 192K
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root 4.0K May  9 21:10 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root   83 May  9 21:11 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 6.5K May  9 21:11 archive_util.py
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root 4.0K May  9 21:10 command
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 2.2K May  9 21:11 compat.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 6.3K May  9 21:11 depends.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  35K May  9 21:11 dist.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 1.7K May  9 21:11 extension.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 5.3K May  9 21:11 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 2.0K May  9 21:11 lib2to3_ex.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 2.2K May  9 21:11 msvc9_support.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  39K May  9 21:11 package_index.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  431 May  9 21:11 py26compat.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  306 May  9 21:11 py27compat.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 1.6K May  9 21:11 py31compat.py
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root 4.0K May  9 21:10 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  14K May  9 21:11 sandbox.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  201 May  9 21:11 script (dev).tmpl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  138 May  9 21:11 script.tmpl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 2.4K May  9 21:11 site-patch.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 8.0K May  9 21:11 ssl_support.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  981 May  9 21:11 unicode_utils.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  293 May  9 21:11 utils.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   21 May  9 21:11 version.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  714 May  9 21:11 windows_support.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be running Python 2.7? It is possible that you have setuptools installed for Python 2.7 and as such you believe it is working just fine.

In order to use setuptools for Python 3.6 you will need it installed for Python 3.6 and not for an older version.

Either way, you can try installing the egg file as is, and from there you will have access to setuptools for Python 3.6.

Comment: under `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, I see setuptools. How do I "install the egg as is"?

Comment: You would need to download the egg file and extract the contents. If you are seeing setuptools in the mentioned directory then it should be working. I'd recommend what the other user said, 'apt-get pip' and then you will be able to 'pip install' whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip with : apt-get install pip

Comment: there's no apt on centos

Comment: and yum exist ?

Comment: because you can maybe install pip with the command line : yum -y install python-pip